# WebFluxSecurity - @PreAuthorize with or/and conditions fails with exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am getting an exception when I try to use the **'and'** condition in the **@PreAuthorize** Spring Boot annotation in the WebFlux mode. When I work with the regular WebSecurity all works as expected.

The exception is:

```
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.ReactiveExpressionUtils.lambda$evaluateAsBoolean$0(ReactiveExpressionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer<?> to java.lang.Boolean
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:87) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.ExpressionUtils.convertTypedValue(ExpressionUtils.java:57) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:188) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getBooleanValue(OpAnd.java:57) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getValueInternal(OpAnd.java:52) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:188) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getBooleanValue(OpAnd.java:57) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getValueInternal(OpAnd.java:48) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:188) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpOr.getBooleanValue(OpOr.java:56) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpOr.getValueInternal(OpOr.java:51) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpOr.getValueInternal(OpOr.java:37) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:273) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.ReactiveExpressionUtils.lambda$evaluateAsBoolean$1(ReactiveExpressionUtils.java:37) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer<?>] to type [java.lang.Boolean]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:82) ~[spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 262 common frames omitted
```

Environment: **Spring Boot 3.0.1, Java 17**

My server uses the standard Spring boot Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity(useAuthorizationManager=true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .csrf().disable().build();
    }
}
```

The PreAuthorize functions class look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PreAuthorizeFunctionsReactive {
    
    @Bean
    public Function<String, Mono<Boolean>> hasParam() {
        return (param) -> Mono.defer(() -> getJwtToken().map(jwt -> Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaimAsString("param"))
            .orElse("")
            .equalsIgnoreCase(param)));
    }

    private Mono<Jwt> getJwtToken() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
                .cast(Jwt.class);
   }

}
```

The controller class looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/test")
@Slf4j
public class TestControllerReactive {

    @PostMapping(path = "/auth/{param}/test", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin') and @hasParam.apply(#param)")
    public Mono<String> testPreAuthorize(
        @RequestBody Flux<Part> parts,
        @PathVariable Mono<String> param) {
        return Mono.just("OK");
    }
}
```

I tried several variants of the @PreAuthorize format:

1. @PreAuthorize(@hasParam.apply(#param)") - working as expected
2. @PreAuthorize(@hasParam.apply(#param) and @hasSome.apply(#param)") - fails with the exception above
3. @PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin') and @hasParam.apply(#param)") - fails with the exception above

I assume that the 'and'/'or' operators does not know how to work with Reactive/Mono objects that the @hasParam.apply(#param) returns.

So, the question is, is there a way to override the 'and'/'or' operators (what did I miss in the configuration)?